# Center coordinate of a coordinate region

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview, coordinates, geography

I have 2 coordinates, a top left and a bottom right. I would like to find the center point of the region. Right now I have the following method to calculate it. The center point is way off. When I call the method with

```
[self.map setRegionTopLeft: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(21.57524, -157.984514)
               bottomRight: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(21.309766, -157.80766)
                  animated:YES];
```

It should center on the island of Oahu in the State of Hawaii, USA. I found this math [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170911010235/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/70471.html) so I'm not sure whats going on.

**Code A** - This is way off. It's not putting me anywhere near the island.

```
- (CLLocationCoordinate2D)centerPointFromRegionTopLeft:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)topLeft
                                           bottomRight:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)bottomRight
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D centerPoint;
    
    centerPoint.longitude = (topLeft.longitude + bottomRight.longitude) / 2;
    if (fabs(bottomRight.longitude - topLeft.longitude) > 180)
    {
        if (centerPoint.longitude > 0)
        {
            centerPoint.longitude = centerPoint.longitude + 180;
        } else {
            centerPoint.longitude = centerPoint.longitude - 180;
        }
    }
    
    centerPoint.latitude = asin((sin(bottomRight.latitude) + sin(topLeft.latitude))/2);
    
    return centerPoint;
}
```

I've also, originally, tried this method. Its just what popped in my head when I thought center of a rectangle. If gets me a lot closer to what the center should be - I can see the island - but its still off.

**Code B** - Original code I tried. This is much closer to what I expected but still off.

```
- (CLLocationCoordinate2D)centerPointFromRegionTopLeft:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)topLeft
                                           bottomRight:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)bottomRight
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D centerPoint;
    
    centerPoint.latitude =  ((topLeft.latitude + bottomRight.latitude) / 2);
    centerPoint.longitude = ((topLeft.longitude + bottomRight.longitude) / 2);
    
    return centerPoint;
}
```

So given a coordinate region (topLeft, bottomRight) how to I get the center coordinate? The idea is I should be able to give any 2 coordinates and get the center coordinate.

**Update*** Code B works. I had my topLeft and bottomRight wrong. Code A puts me very south and a little east of where it should.

Comment: The 3rd maths looks right to me, that asin/sin stuff is a neat solution to the spherical problem. How far off was it?

Comment: @Craig - I'll have to check over lunch when I can get to my laptop. I'll post an update when I can.

Comment: Code B doesn't take into account the antemeridian. It may never need to in your code, but you could pinch a bit from Code A and make it span the world correctly

Comment: @Craig, the latitude or longitude bit? Ideally this I would like this to work for any 2 coordinates that are passed in.

Comment: Latitudes don't cross the antemeridian.

Answer (score 0):

You need the middle of L(longitude) and B(latitude). For B the problem is around the pole, but as you set it, you simply can't "put the cap on the pole", so, really no problems here.

```
Middle(B1,B2)=(B1+B2)/2.
```

But L is much worse. L can jump from -179 to -179. And another problem : the middle of (-179,+179) should be 180, and middle(-1,+1) should be 0. I.e., we should always choose middle along shorter way between opposite points, not around the whole Earth.

We should move the zero meridian so, that the difference between L1,L2 will be smaller, than 180, make normal middle of them and then return the zero meridian back.

- Let L1

  if L2-L1>180, let's choose L2 for the new zero meridian.

  - shift=L2
  - L2=L2-shift, L1=L1+360-shift. Now, notice, L1-L2<180!
  - LmShifted=(L1+L2)/2
  - Lm=LmShifted+shift.
  - If we'll take these formulas together, we'll have:
  - Lm=(L1-L2+360)/2+L2

  if L2-L1<180, Lm=(L1+L2)/2

The problem is when L2-L1=180. In this case you have two opposite meridians, dividing the Earth in two, and for the role of the middle both "quarter" meridian, to the right and to the left, fit. It's up to you, what to choose.